# SQL Server Is there a way to select columns from a given list

Tags: sql-server, dynamic-sql

I have a list of columns that are dynamic then select the column in table that are in the list.

For example

```
Select (List of columns) 
from tablename
```

Here is my code

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @table TABLE(cols varchar(50));

DECLARE @tablename NVARCHAR(255);
DECLARE @tableid INT;
DECLARE @sSQL NVARCHAR(500);

SET @tableid = (SELECT DISTINCT TABLEID FROM faciltyShowedDetails WHERE layerid = @layerid);
SET @tablename = (SELECT dbo.FNC_Search_GetSearchTable(@tableid))

INSERT INTO @table(cols)
    SELECT COLUMN_NAME 
    FROM faciltyShowedDetails 
    WHERE layerid = @layerid;
```

I want to select from the list of column in `@table`.

Comment: Yes, there is a way but unless you want an abstract solution please provide an actual code that you have.

Comment: What is the form of this list of columns?  Is it a CSV list?

Comment: No i will select the list from a table

Comment: You still have not bothered clarifying your previous question. Is this some kind of question spam scheme? Previous question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45342790/sql-server-filter-column-from-select-from

Comment: i deleted my question just now. its kind of different approach but still the same problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would construct the query and use dynamic SQL.  Assuming the "list" is really a comma-delimited list:

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max);

set @sql = 'select [cols] from tablename';

set @sql = replace(@sql, '[cols]', @cols);

exec sp_executesql @sql;
```

EDIT:

To get the columns from a table, you can use the trick:

```
declare @cols varchar(max);

select @cols = ', ' + columnname
from @table t;
```

You then have to remove the first comma (using `stuff()`) in the previous code.

Comment: i declare the list a table of string how can i use it as your @cols